# Defining a static data member of a templated class within a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I have a class template inside of another class template. The inner class has a static data member. I am struggling to provide a definition for it. The below example works in clang 3.8 but not in gcc-7.1

```
template <typename T>
struct Out {
  template <typename U>
  struct In {
    static int var;
  };
};

template <typename T>
template <typename U>
int Out<T>::template In<U>::var;
```

gcc gives the error:

```
error: template definition of non-template ‘int Out<T>::In<U>::var’
 int Out<T>::template In<U>::var;
                             ^~~
```

What do I gotta do to make gcc happy?

---

Edit: turns out getting rid of `template` make this work:

```
template <typename T>
template <typename U>
int Out<T>::In<U>::var;
```

Which still leaves the question, is `template` allowed here?

Comment: Not just allowed, but needed. At this point, the compiler doesn't know if Out<T>::In is a typename/member/template. It would guess member, and guess you wanted In < U first, then >::, which is an error. Newer gccs, as above, provide useful diagnostics here; before, it was much worse.

Comment: @lorro I thought it was necessary for the reasons you gave. My confusion is confirmed

Answer (score 0):

This type of definition would more commonly be seen without the `template` before `In`.  The `template` keyword is not needed here because `Out<T>::In` is a "member of the current specialization".

For the rule specifying when the `template` keyword is required before a member name, see [temp.names]/4.  For the definition of the technical term "member of the current specialization", see [temp.dep.type]/4.

But the keyword is in fact allowed there, since the grammar permits it between any `::` and name, and the semantics require only that the name that follows is either used with template arguments or names a class template ([temp.names]/5), and there are no other rules in the Standard to forbid it.  And as a note in [temp.names]/5 explains:

> [ *Note:* As is the case with the `typename` prefix, the `template` prefix is allowed in cases where it is not strictly necessary; i.e., when the *nested-name-specifier* or the expression on the left of the `->` or `.` is not dependent on a template parameter, or the use does not appear in the scope of a template. - *end note*]

Comment: I'm still confused about why it wouldn't treat `In` as a static data member of `Out` when `template` is omitted

Comment: The rules about where a redundant `template` disambiguator is allowed changed in C++11. Specifically the part about "the use does not appear in the scope of a template".